# Drawing two .obj files in OpenGL 2

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I have two obj files, one is face/head and another is a hat. I want to put the hat over the face/head. I am able to render these objects separately using opengl2. But i am not able to render hat over the face/head. Can someone please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am asking for the idea to do it